# If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\nu$, then $\frac{{\rm d}\mu}{{\rm d}v}(t)=\liminf\frac{\mu((r,t])}{\nu((r,t])}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

I've read that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures on $[0,\infty)$ (equipped with arbitarary, different, $\sigma$-algebras or both with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?) and $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, then $$\frac{{\rm d}\mu}{{\rm d}v}(t)=\liminf_{r\uparrow t}\frac{\mu((r,t])}{\nu((r,t])}$$ for $\nu$-almost all $t>0$, where the limit inferior is taken with respect to $r<t$, $r$ rational.

How can we prove that?

Comment: Thinking that the problem is by no means trivial even when $\nu$ is a Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$ (which is then the famous Lebesgue differentiation theorem), I guess that the answer can be no easier than this particular case. Indeed, in [one reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154130/radon-nikodym-derivatives-as-limits-of-ratios) it is claimed that we can follow the same idea of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem but using [*Besicovitch covering theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besicovitch_covering_theorem) in place of Vitali covering theorem.